# JavaFX: should I keep scenes in memory?

Tags: java, performance, javafx, memory-management, frontend

In my JavaFX application, I have several distinct scenes to represent popups.

At the start of the application, each scene is instantiated.

As the program is used, I present each popup to the user using 'scene.show()' and 'scene.hide()'.

Therefore, each scene is kept in memory throughout the use of the program.

Would it be more efficient to properly dispose of the scene when hiding  it, and re-instantiate it when the view is requested again? Or would instantiation take some time?

The reason I ask is that sometimes the program is using nearly 2GB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you value more in the program, speed (CPU) or efficient use of memory.

Since creating and destroying new scenes takes longer than changing their visibility however is more memory efficient, and vice versa.

Really depends on your needs for the program and the amount of use each scene sees.